# Making a COM dll to be invoked from c#, HRESULT error handling?

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm making a COM interface that c# will be using, however i am wondering how i am to check for errors for exception handling on the c# end. As at the moment i am just returning a HRESTULT or bool for most methods and then doing a Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR  but several things can go wrong in some of these methods and returning a E_FAIL just doesn't cut it.

What can i do in order to return more information? Can i make a HRESULT of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually done this, but in theory you should be able to do it by [supporting IErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfkzz72z%28VS.80%29.aspx). `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR()` has an overload that takes an IErrorInfo pointer.

By the way, you should not have to manually call `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR()` - if your method returns HRESULT and and `[out]` parameter for the return value you can declare it in .NET as returning the return value and [set PreserveSig=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig.aspx) and the CLR will automatically throw an exception if the HRESULT indicates a failure.